# Error code 2318 while uninstalling python 3.6.3

Tags: python, windows-10

I am trying to uninstall python 3.6.3 ,but it always gives me this pop up

```
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package.
This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2318.
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What did you discover when you investigated the error code?

Comment: While i was uninstalling the python this error appeared ,but when the uninstallation procedure ended  it gave me the 0x80070643 error code. I tried lots of things to remove this error ,but the computer still gives me the same error codes.

Comment: Yes, but what did you find when you Googled those codes? Posting a question on SO is a request to clarify some problem that confuses you, and that request must be preceded by your own research to try to find the information you need. SO is not a help desk; it is an information sharing site.

Comment: Reason why I posted this question is that I couldn't find any usable information about this
error code, anything that could help me. I thought that someone who had
the same problem could give me an advice or taught me the right way to 
solve the problem. I understand what SO is and I am not the type of person 
who is lazy to solve there problems.

Comment: It isn't a question of being lazy. It's a matter of repeatedly identifying what information you're missing and looking for it; then you need to explain what you know already and what you're missing in the question. This is the second result when I searched for "windows uninstall error code 2318": https://github.com/jasongin/nvs/issues/22#issuecomment-266092967. What information are you missing that prevents you from understanding how to apply that knowledge? Have you searched for that? You have to *keep looking* until you run out of things to look for.

Comment: I don't know if the link that you have included has anything to do with the problem that I have. The reason why this error appears ( if you are uninstalling or installing some sort of program ) is that you have installed the program ,but didn't uninstall it correctly ( uninstalled it manually instead of uninstalling it from the control panel ) at first I thought it was an OS problem ,but the reason of the error appearing is the program package itself. (I am still looking for solutions and I think I have found one).

Comment: It most likely does. Read it and understand the problem it's identifying. It says that the error is caused by a path that exceeds the `MAX_PATH` length. That happening in your Python installation directory is completely plausible. If so, then clearing out the problem path would allow you to uninstall. My guess is some package installed very deep directories under `site-packages`. So the question is: why didn't that occur to you? What knowledge were you missing? If you had identified that, you could have figured this out yourself.

Comment: The reason why I am asking this question is that I don't know many things about this error code. I am trying to learn from people who know better than me how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for the problrm is...
(UNHIDE ALL FOLDERS BEFORE FOLLOWING DOWN...)

1)Go to C:\Users\ (Current User Name)\AppData\Local\Programs

note: If you can not find your python folder using this address

...1) Repair your python installation ( see 3,4 and 5 steps )
     don't forget to add python to path

...2) Open cmd and write python

...3) This will open up python IDLE

...4) Then use this code:
     
     `import sys
     print(sys.executable)`

...5) Use the given address and you will find your python folder

2)Delete Python Folder

3)Go to Control Panel >> Uninstall a Program

4)Right Click on Python and then Change/Modify

5)Click on Repair Python. Note: This will Fail but be Patient

6)Now Again go to step 3

7)Now, after step 3, uninstall Python

8)Now Install a new fresh version